# Check data attribute values in multiple divs with click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a selected group of divs to change the background color based off of data set in the buttons data attribute.

I've done some digging, but I'm getting confused on how to pass the conditional against the title in the div and the data in the data attribute from the button.

I know I have to possibly `.split()` the data out of the button since there is more than one data attribute for each button. But then getting that info and getting to check again the set of divs is where I *think* I'm getting hung up on.

Here's what I have so far:

**Codepen Link:** https://codepen.io/ultraloveninja/pen/bmvOYB

**HTML:**

```
<section class="state-group">
  <div class="state" title="Illinois">
    <h2>Illinois</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="state" title="New Hampshire">
    <h2>New Hampshire</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="state" title="Washington">
    <h2>Washington</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="state" title="North Dakota">
    <h2>North Dakota</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="state" title="South Dakota">
    <h2>South Dakota</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="state" title="Wisconsin">
    <h2>Wisconsin</h2>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="btn-group">
  <a data-state='New Hampshire,Illinois,Wisconsin' class="region region-one" href="">Region 1</a>
  <a data-state='Illinois,Washington,North Dakota' class="region region-two" href="">Region 2</a>
  <a data-state='Washington,North Dakota,South Dakota' class="region region-three" href="">Region 3</a>
</section>
```

**JS:**

```
var $region = $('.region').data("state");
var $single = $region.split(',');

$(".region").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".state-group div").each(function() {
    var $state = $(this).attr("title");
    if ($state == $single ) {
      $(this).css('background-color','blue')
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Basically, once you click the button it will check the data from the button you clicked on, find the title of the div (in this case the state) and if it matches, make the background of those specific divs blue.

Again, not sure if I'm going about this the correct way, or if I need to get the data from the divs and store that in a variable as well. Hope that make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get state from the clicked button, not when js load. So that you will have states based on the clicked button.

```
$(".region").on("click", function(e) {
  //Below line is important; Otherwise it won't work for other buttons.
  var $single = $(this).data("state").split(",");

  $(".state-group div").each(function() {
    var $state = $(this).attr("title");
    if ($single.indexOf($state) > -1) {
      $(this).css('background-color','blue');
    }else{
      $(this).css('background-color','#ccc');
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyRgEZ

Comment: Ah ha! Ok, I see now. Yeah, I was testing it out within the click of the button, but I wasn't sure at what point I needed to store the variable for the state data so I could pass that back in the conditional. But this works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

```
var $region = $('.region').data("state");
var $single = $region.split(',');

$(".region").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".state-group div").each(function() {
    var $state = $(this).attr("title");

    // HERE 
    if ($single.includes($state)) {
      $(this).css('background-color','blue')
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to keep reference of each state in the data, rather than use `data-state` & use the same value as class of the relevant element.So on click get the `data-state` & from the dom get the element which have same class and highlight them.

The benefit of this length of the value of `data-state` will not increase with increase of new element

```js
$(".region").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let getDataState = $(this).data('state')
  $('.' + getDataState).css('background-color', 'blue')

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.state-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.state {
  flex: 0 1 13%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  a {
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    background: lighten(blue, 20%);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="state-group">
  <div class="state btn-1 btn-2" title="Illinois">
    <h2>Illinois</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="state btn-1" title="New Hampshire">
    <h2>New Hampshire</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="state btn-2 btn-3" title="Washington">
    <h2>Washington</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="state btn-2 btn-3" title="North Dakota">
    <h2>North Dakota</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="state btn-3" title="South Dakota">
    <h2>South Dakota</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="state btn-1" title="Wisconsin">
    <h2>Wisconsin</h2>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="btn-group">
  <a data-state='btn-1' class="region region-one" href="">Region 1</a>
  <a data-state='btn-2' class="region region-two" href="">Region 2</a>
  <a data-state='btn-3' class="region region-three" href="">Region 3</a>
</section>
```